# Geo My WP - Create Dropdown Menu Search Input

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have learned a lot from this forum and finally I am in need of specific help. If someone can help me solve this, you will have my eternal gratitude.

**Framework**: 
Wordpress site that has Buddypress(BP) and GEO My WP installed. Each user has a certain set of BP profile fields that Geo My WP uses to search through and return the results.

**Goal**: On the Geo My WP search form, I wish to have a dropdown list that a user can select one item; for example "Hockey". This selected item is then used to search through two (2) different BP xprofile fields (eg: "Main Sports" & "Casual Sports"). These two BP xprofile fields will be populated by the admin and they will both be a text line with single terms separated by a comma; for example "Basketball, Football, Soccer, Hockey" etc. 
If the user selected term matches a term in either of the two BP xprofile fields, Geo My WP will return the BP profile in the search results.

**Problem**: I can't figure out how to do this. If both BP xprofile fields are selected to search through in Geo My WP settings, then both show up on the search form. I need it to be only one input in the search field.

I have run out of ideas on manipulating the code and would appreciate some fresh eyes on this problem.

Many thanks,

MM.

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing some JS changes to your form. That would not be perfect, but worked at least in my case. Here's an example of what I mean.

```
jQuery('#gmw-address-1').remove();
jQuery('#gmw-address-field-wrapper-1').prepend('*');
```

### In your case

You'd need to bind two events: `documentReady` and `change` for the select you will create.

#### on `documentReady`

1. get values from selects you want to join together
2. replace selects with hiden fields
3. create select combining those two you've just replaced

#### on `change`

1. check chosen value
2. match it with plausible values to determine witch select it belongs to
3. update the hidden field you matched in pt. 2 with value from pt.1